# Excel Macro - Loop: Find xlPart instances, assign its adjacent value to array

Tags: arrays, excel, for-loop, find, vba

I'm not real good at macros/VB - I've had some experience that mostly amounts to struggling through writing a line while searching all over Google for examples.

I'm trying to write a macro function that will assign 12 items into an array and pass that array to its parent Sub (the main) (so I can put each array item into a cell in a different worksheet). The values are found by looking for "markers" in the first column (will always be "M1" through "M6" and will always be adjacent down the rows, but will *not* always have all 6 markers - sometimes there are less). Then I'm trying to grab the two values in the second and third columns next to each marker and plug each value into an item in the array.

What I'm down to at this point is finding "M1", resizing the range around it to include 6 rows total. Then my plan was to search within those 6 rows to see whether the left character begins with "M" and if it does to grab each of the two adjacent columns' values and plug them into two array items - and if not to assign "N/A" to all remaining array items.

Not sure if that's the best way, or if it even describes it well, but that's where I'm stuck - I don't know how to look in the cell to see if the left character is "M" and then copy the two adjacent columns' value into my array. Here's the code so far:

```
Function GetMarkerArray() As String() 'grabs all the marker values present
    ' from CSV or sets "N/A" if not and passes it along to the main sub for use.
Dim markerArray(11) As String 'this will hold all the marker values
Dim c As Integer 'create a quick counter variable
    c = 1 'initiate the counter
Dim a As Integer 'create a quick array counter variable
    a = 0 'zero out the array counter
Dim markerCell As Range 'this holds location of "M1" marker found
Dim markRow As Integer 'this holds the row of each marker
Dim cell As Range 'quick range value for lookup

    With ActiveSheet.Range("a:a") 'doing things inside the active sheet of the CSV file
    '====================================================================================
    'find location of "M1" (the first marker) exapand the range, and store it. This range will be used later
    'to find all marker values instances and assign each value next to it to an entry in the array or
    'assign "N/A" for remaining array items w/o markers.
    Set markerCell = Range("a:a").Find(What:="M1", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Resize(6)
            '====================
            'temp - for testing
            MsgBox markerCell.Address
    '====================================================================================
            markRow = markerCell.row 'set the row that "M1" was found in
    End With

    For c = 1 To markerCell.Rows.Count
        'code: if left letter = "M" then
            'markerArray(a) = cells(markerCell,2).value
            'a = a + 1
            'markerArray(a) = cells(markerCell,3).value
            'a = a + 1
        'code: else loop through remaining array items and set to "N/A"
    Next c

GetMarkerArray = markerArray
End Function
```

Any ideas big or small are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going into the details of the code and your explanation, is that the function in VB/VBA called Left(string, len) you are looking for. 
Eg:

```
if Left(cells(c,1), 1) = "M" then
```

I will further look into more details, if this is not just enough.

**Update 1:**

If I understand what you asked correctly below is the code which works to get marker data.

[image]

And here are few changes I made to your code,

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L
'

Dim marker() As String
    Dim res As String
    marker = GetMarkerArray
    For i = LBound(marker) To UBound(marker)
        res = res & marker(i) & ", "
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then res = res & vbCrLf
    Next i
    MsgBox "Array Values: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & res
End Sub

Function GetMarkerArray() As String() 'grabs all the marker values present
    ' from CSV or sets "N/A" if not and passes it along to the main sub for use.
Dim markerArray(11) As String 'this will hold all the marker values
Dim c As Integer 'create a quick counter variable
    c = 1 'initiate the counter
Dim a As Integer 'create a quick array counter variable
    a = 0 'zero out the array counter
Dim markerCell As Range 'this holds location of "M1" marker found
Dim markRow As Integer 'this holds the row of each marker
Dim cell As Range 'quick range value for lookup
Dim markerFinished As Boolean
    With ActiveSheet.Range("a:a") 'doing things inside the active sheet of the CSV file
    '====================================================================================
    'find location of "M1" (the first marker) exapand the range, and store it. This range will be used later
    'to find all marker values instances and assign each value next to it to an entry in the array or
    'assign "N/A" for remaining array items w/o markers.
    Set markerCell = Range("a:a").Find(What:="M1", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Resize(6)
            '====================
            'temp - for testing
            MsgBox markerCell.Address
    '====================================================================================
            markRow = markerCell.Row 'set the row that "M1" was found in
    End With
    markerFinished = False
    For c = 1 To markerCell.Rows.Count
        'code: if left letter = "M" then
        If Left(UCase(Trim(markerCell(c, 1))), 1) = "M" And Not markerFinished Then
            'markerArray(a) = cells(markerCell,2).value
            markerArray(a) = markerCell(c, 2)
            a = a + 1
            markerArray(a) = markerCell(c, 3)
            a = a + 1
        Else
            markerFinished = True
            markerArray(a) = "N/A"
            a = a + 1
            markerArray(a) = "N/A"
            a = a + 1
        End If
        'code: else loop through remaining array items and set to "N/A"
    Next c

GetMarkerArray = markerArray
End Function
```

**Update 2:**

Answer for you question in the comment is, Find function fails to get a range when M1 is not found. But, the statement goes further with "no range", to call Resize(6) function which throws the error. Below is a bit fine tuned code to address that,

```
Function GetMarkerArray() As String() 'grabs all the marker values present
    ' from CSV or sets "N/A" if not and passes it along to the main sub for use.
Dim markerArray(11) As String 'this will hold all the marker values
Dim c As Integer 'create a quick counter variable
    c = 1 'initiate the counter
Dim a As Integer 'create a quick array counter variable
    a = 0 'zero out the array counter
Dim markerCell As Range 'this holds location of "M1" marker found
Dim markRow As Integer 'this holds the row of each marker
Dim cell As Range 'quick range value for lookup
Dim markerFinished As Boolean
    Set markerCell = ActiveSheet.Range("a:a").Find(What:="M1", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    If markerCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Markers found"
        For c = 0 To 11
            markerArray(c) = "N/A"
        Next c
    Else
        Set markerCell = markerCell.Resize(6)
        markerFinished = False
        For c = 1 To markerCell.Rows.Count
            If Left(UCase(Trim(markerCell(c, 1))), 1) = "M" And Not markerFinished Then
                markerArray(a) = markerCell(c, 2)
                a = a + 1
                markerArray(a) = markerCell(c, 3)
                a = a + 1
            Else
                markerFinished = True
                markerArray(a) = "N/A"
                a = a + 1
                markerArray(a) = "N/A"
                a = a + 1
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    GetMarkerArray = markerArray
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, Naren - I'm looking at this now, but at a glance it looks outstanding. Be back shortly.

Comment: Not sure why "markerArray (1 to 12)" instead of just "markerArray(11)" - changing that, but the reason would help me learn.

removed the line markerStarted = True (a couple lines below the "For C" loop) - appears like it was the beginning of an idea that was discarded.

Comment: Nothing special about the array declaration. Before getting this final code I was trying few other things with your code. These are results of that, including "markerStarted=true" which I removed then. Array declaration can be either way, change it if you want. Overall, does this answer get what you expected?

Comment: Ok. changed the array declaration as in the way it was :)

Comment: Looks like this works - thank you very much for the fast responses, answer, and updates!

Comment: Not sure if it's ok to add a question here - the following line fails out if "M1" isn't found, I thought that wouldn't happen, but in testing it just now it did happen. What's the way to fix that? `Set markerCell = Range("a:a").Find(What:="M1", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Resize(6)`

Comment: @JGR, Updated the answer to your question in the comment above. Please check "Update 2" in the answer.